# Separated by the Meridian polygons in geomaps SAS VA (SAS GRAPH)

Tags: sas, shapefile, geomap, sas-visual-analytics

I'm trying create custom maps to Russia in Visual Analytics.
So, I've faced with a trouble of "separated region".
You can see a visualization of this problem by using `Dal'nevostochnyy (DVFO)` region from `MAPSGFK` library. 
[image]

I tried to fix the scatter by this code:

```
data mps.vaasia1;
set mps.vaasia1;
if LONG < 0 and isoalpha2="RU" then long=long+360 ; 
run;
```

And so I get this result *(on picture imaged region `Chukotka`, but it dosen't matter)*:

[image]
It's better then previous situation, but it's look like *crutch*.
I've try to combine this two polygons by using [`GREMOVE`](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/graphref/63022/HTML/default/viewer.htm#gremove-concepts.htm) (also add paramether `FUZZ`), but result was as the same.

**UPD:**
I use this code to get coordinates:

```
data ch;
set mapsgfk.Russia;
where id ="RU-77" ;
if LONG LE 0 then  long=long+360 ; 
x=long ;
y = lat;
run;
```

[image]

So my question is:
How can I delete space between two **separated** regions?

Thx for your answers / comments.

Comment: Can you include the full code for generating that map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks [@Jor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1623007/joe) for you post. Your answer pushed me to thought: "May be I can't merge two poligons because they don't have common points?". So, I saw  task like this:

1. Remove points between polygons *(Red squares in picture below)*
2. Set edge's polygons dots coordinates equal *(Blue arrows)*

[image]

```
data ch
/*Drop out dots with coord in red squares*/
(where=(not(lat > 66 and lat <68 and long >179 and long<181) ));
set mapsgfk.Russia;
where id ="RU-77" ;

if LONG LE 0 then  long=long+360 ; 

/*Set coordinates of near edge's points the same*/
if (long > 179.9 and long < 180.3) then do; 
    long =180;
    if (lat > 68.9 and lat < 69) then lat=68.97;
    if (lat > 65 and lat < 65.1) then lat=65;
    if (lat > 70.9 and lat < 71) then lat=70.95;
    if (lat > 71.5 and lat < 71.6) then lat=71.55;
end;

x=long ;
y = lat;
run;

proc gremove data=ch out=ch;
by id;
id id1;
run;


proc gmap data=ch map=ch;
id id;
choro id/nolegend;
run;
quit;
```

Result:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work, at least for the specific issue.  The issue is that the `segment` is not the same for these, so they get a border.  Doing this in a more general way I'm not sure if there's a good way or not; there probably is a better way, perhaps using `GPROJECT`, that would avoid the issue entirely.

But this works, at least for this specific issue...

```
data vaasia1;
set mapsgfk.asia1;
if LONG LE 0 and isoalpha2="RU" then do;
  long=long+360 ; 
  if segment=2 then segment=1;
  else if segment=7 then segment=8;
end;
if idname =: 'Dal';
*if long le 0;
run;


proc gmap data=vaasia1 map=vaasia1;
id id;
choro id/nolegend;
run;
quit;
```